# What are hymns chanted for abhishekam?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, ganesha

If Rudram, Namakam & chamakam are related to Shiva, why they are chanted for abhishekam of other gods?

Are there any other prominent alternative hymns for abhishekam?

Are they chanted only in shiva-agama or it is same in vishnu-agama?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all there is a *Panchayatan* (formation for offering puja), in this we perform Abhishek to the Aaradhya (main) god for which we are offering puja.

There are following possibilities for Aradhya and other god's

1. Any Male God(Except Shiva) we use *Purusha Sukta*
2. Lord Narayana(Vishnu) and all his 24 avatar's we use *Vishnu Sukta* (notice we can also use Purusha Sukta instead) each 11 times for Abhishek.
3. Lord Shiva we use *Rudram* also known *Rudradhya*. The *Rudradyaya* can be done 11 times it makes one *Laghu Rudra*

   - 11 Rudra Path = 1 Laghu Rudra
   - 11 Laghu Rudra = 1 MahaRudra
   - 11 MahaRudra= 1 Ati Rudra
4. All Devi's (female Godess) we use, *Shri Sukta*, also Lakshmi Sukta can be used for special pujas like Deepawali Pujan.
5. While doing Navgraha Puja and Performing Abhishekam we use *Saura Sukta* for Sun God.
6. For Ganpati or Ganesha people perform Abhishek by reciting Ganpati Atharvasirsha which is widely [considered as an interpolation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3012/489).

(A general Note : All These Suktas' are Derived from Vedas' and has to be sung like the vedic hymns , with full knowledge of how  vedic hynms or mantras are chanted)

[This](http://www.advaita-vedanta.org/articles/panchayatana_puja.htmtyhin) has more details on Panchayatan.

---

In Vaishnava temples, First Vishvaksenar is Worshipped for removing obstacles, then Shriman Narayana is worshipped with abhishekam by Purusha suktam, Sri Suktam(since Sri devi or Thayar resides in his heart).

Devi Laxmi is then attended with Sri Suktam and other preferred stotras.

Answer (score 2):

I will give an answer based on Vaishnava texts since you are interested in deities other than Shiva. [Śrīmad Bhāgavatam 11.27.31](https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n2115/mode/2up) lists some hymns to be chanted during bathing the deity, "svarṇa-gharmānuvākena mahāpuruṣa-vidyayā pauruṣeṇāpi sūktena sāmabhī rājanādibhiḥ". The hymns are called the svarṇa-gharmānuvāka, mahāpuruṣa-vidya, puruṣa-sūkta and rājanā. The **svarṇa-gharmānuvāka** comes from the Taittirīya Āraṇyaka 3.11.1. The text is given in this answer: [What does the Suvarna Gharma Anuvaka of the Taittiriya Aranyaka mean?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/what-does-the-suvarna-gharma-anuvaka-of-the-taittiriya-aranyaka-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1) **Mahāpuruṣa-vidya** is described in [Vijayatīrtha's commentary](https://archive.org/details/SrimadBhagavatamCanto11withMultipleSanskritCommentaries/page/n1171/mode/2up), "mahāpuruṣavidyayā jitaṃ te puṇḍarīkākṣetyādikayā pauruṣeṇa". This refers to the [Jitante Stotram](https://archive.org/details/jitante_stotram/), which begins with the same words. Jitante Stotram is also recommended in [Jayākhyasaṃhitā 13.222-223](https://archive.org/details/jayakhya/page/n249/mode/2up). **Puruṣa-sūkta** is very well-known, and from Ṛgveda 10.90. **Rājanā** comes from Kauthumasaṃhitā #318 and Ṛgveda 7.27.1.

Vijayatīrtha's commentary lists some extra hymns that can be added, "svasya suktena viṣṇusūktena... sūktaṃ samudrādūmiriti pāvīryāyetyādisūktaṃ stūyamānaṃ sūktaṃ nīrājanam". That means, the **Viṣṇusūkta** (Ṛgveda 1.154), **Samudrasūkta** (Ṛgveda 4.58) and **Pavamānasukta** (Taittirīyasaṃhitā 5.6.1) can also be sung.

Answer (score 1):

For Shiva Abhishekam, is the greatest Abhishekam that's why Lord Shiva is called as Abhishek priya.

The greatest and the highest Abhishekam is to pour the waters of pure love on the Aatm Ling of the lotus of the heart. The external Abhishekam with various objects will help the growth of devotion and adoration for Shiv and eventually lead to internal Abhishekam  with pure abundant flow of love.

Abhishek is a part of Shiv Poojaa. Without Abhishekam, worship of Shiv is incomplete. **During Shiva Abhishekam Rudra, Purusha Suktam, Chamakam, Maha Mrityunjaya mantra etc, are chanted in a particular rhythm and order.** Monday is very important day for Shiv and the 13th day of the fortnight ( Pradosh) is very sacred. On these days, devotees of Shiv worship him with special Poojaa, Abhishekam with Ekaadash Rudra, Archanaa, offering plenty of Prasaad, and illumination.

In Ekaadash-Rudram Abhishek, every Rudram is chanted with distinctive articles for Abhishek. Gangaa water, milk, ghee, honey, rose-water, coconut water, sandal paste, Panchaamrit, scented oil, sugarcane juice and lime juice are made use of for Abhishekam. After every Abhishek, pure water is poured over the head of Shiva Ling. When Rudra is recited only once, the different articles of Abhishek are made use of after every stanza of the Rudram. The Abhishekam water or other articles used for Abhishekam are considered very sacred and bestow immense benefits on the devotees who take it as the Lord’s Prasaad. It purifies the heart and destroys countless sins. You must take it with intense Bhaav and faith.

For more go [here](https://www.templepurohit.com/shiva-abhishekam-procedure-benefits/amp/)...

As for Purusha Shuktam, Like Namakam, Chamakam, Rudram, etc it's also used for other deities.

According to Ishwara Gita chapter 7.:

> सावित्री सर्वजप्यानां गुह्यानां प्रणवोऽस्म्यहम् ।
> सूक्तानां पौरुषं सूक्तं ज्येष्ठसाम च सामसु ॥ ७.१३॥
> Meaning: - Among all the Japa (chantings) know me to be Savitri Mantra, among the confidential (elements) know me to be Pranava (Omkara). **Among suktas (of Veda) know me to be Purush Sukta,** among Sama (Veda) know me to ne Jyesth sAman.

The Taittirya Aranyaka(10:24:1) of Yajur Veda clearly says .:

> **Lord Rudra is 'Veda Purusha' (purusho vai rudrah).**

Now, Why all these mantras and suktams are used for different different dieties.?

It's because worship of all deities culminates in the worship of the Brahman. And the vice versa is also true that all the worship goes to the Brahman only.

According to Nirvana Upanishad, how a yogi achieves Nirvana aka Moksha is given.:

> विष्णुविद्यादिशताभिधानलक्ष्यम् ।
> **The (worship of) gods named Vishnu, Brahma and a hundred others culminates (in Brahman).** (Verse 29).

And Who is that Brahman after oneness with whom a yogi gets nirvana.:

> परापवादमुक्तो जीवन्मुक्तः | शिवयोगनिद्रा च ।
> **Liberated while alive, as they are freed from denial of the highest (Brahman). The oneness with Siva is their sleep.** (Verse 24-25).

So, According to Vedas all are the parts of Brahman only therefore the same mantras and shuktam can be used for different dieties also due to their Non-Dual (Advaitam) nature.
.
I hope it's a bit clearer now.