# Available sources for the 108 Upanishads?

Tags: vedas, upanishads, translation-request

Although we know that there are 108 Upanishads, only 12 are popular in discourse and it is said that most of the original copies of Upanishads were lost or stolen from Hindu mutts by the Western Indologists. What are the names of the 108 Upanishads? Is the list given in [this](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/upalist.asp) accurate? Also a 1 line description of what each of these Upanishads deal will be of great help.

P.S. It is said that the most authentic record of the Upanishads available is Darah Shikoh's translation of around 50 Upanishads. Is there a book that is a compilation of Shikoh's and all the available (Indian) translation of upanishads?

Comment: They were not lost or stolen by the Indologists. It is believed that there were many more than the 108 but some died out because the brahmin family died out, others were destroyed during Muslim invasions. There is no way to really ascertain how many there were originally or how they were lost. Never heard of Darah Shikoh. There are many good translations available. The best are not on the internet.

Comment: These 108 Upanishads on the list in the Muktika Upanishad are only those that are considered the foremost, but it has been preserved more than 230 Upanishads. Sometimes people ask: How do we know which of these Upanishads are authentic? There is only one way of how this can be reliably determined. It is said that the Upanishads are "Shruti", which means "listening". Traditionally the Upanishads have been transmitted in oral tradition (by listening from the guru), ...

Comment: ... so if an oral tradition for some Upanishad is preserved over the centuries starting from Vyasadeva it is the only reliable evidence of its authenticity. There's no other way to accurately establish the authenticity of some Upanishad, it is really the only reliable way! Now, the problem is that for most of the Upanishads oral tradition has not survived, so there is no reliable evidence of their authenticity. But that does not mean that they do not have to be authentic, so that some Hindus accept even those Upanishads, and some Hindus are skeptical.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Shruti doesn't mean "that which was heard from a guru" - both Shruti and Smriti were passed down through oral tradition from guru to shishya.  Shruti means "that which is heard by sages during Tapasya", and Smriti refers to humanly composed texts whose origin is remembered and passed down along a Parampara.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan In my comment I have not explained the meaning of the words Shruti and Smriti. My point was to explain that there is only one way to establish the authenticity of an Upanishad.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa Sorry, I misinterpreted your statement "It is said that the Upanishads are "Shruti", which means "listening". Traditionally the Upanishads have been transmitted in oral tradition (by listening from the guru)" as an explanation of what "listening" means in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional list of 108 Upanishads is given in the Muktika Upanishad, which you can read [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090805184434/http://geocities.com/advaitavedant/muktika.htm):

> 1. Isa
> 2. Kena
> 3. Katha
> 4. Prasna
> 5. Munda
> 6. Mandukya
> 7. Taittiri
> 8. Aitareya
> 9. Chandogya
> 10. Brihadaranyaka
> 11. Brahma
> 12. Kaivalya
> 13. Jabala
> 14. Svetasva
> 15. Hamsa
> 16. Aruni
> 17. Garbha
> 18. Narayana
> 19. Paramahamsa
> 20. Amritabindu
> 21. Amritanada
> 22. Atahrvasirah
> 23. Atharvasikha
> 24. Maitrayini
> 25. Kaushitakibrahmana
> 26. Brihajjabala
> 27. Nrisimhatapini
> 28. Kalagnirudra
> 29. Maitreya
> 30. Subala
> 31. Kshurika
> 32. Mantrika
> 33. Sarvasara
> 34. Niralamba
> 35. Sukarahasya
> 36. Vajrasuchika
> 37. Tejobindu
> 38. Nadabindu
> 39. Dhyanabindu
> 40. Brahmavidya
> 41. Yogatattva
> 42. Atmabodha
> 43. Naradaparivrajaka
> 44. Trisikhi
> 45. Sita
> 46. Yogachudamani
> 47. Nirvana
> 48. Mandalabrahmana
> 49. Dakshinamurti
> 50. Sarabha
> 51. Skanda
> 52. Tripadvibhuti-Mahanarayana
> 53. Advayataraka
> 54. Ramarahasya
> 55. Ramatapani
> 56. Vasudeva
> 57. Mudgala
> 58. Sandilya
> 59. Paingala
> 60. Bhiksu
> 61. Mahat
> 62. Sariraka
> 63. Yogasikha
> 64. Turiyatita
> 65. Sannyasa
> 66. Paramahamsaparivrajaka
> 67. Akshamalika
> 68. Avyakta
> 69. Ekakshara
> 70. Annapurna
> 71. Surya
> 72. Akshi
> 73. Adhyatma
> 74. Kundika
> 75. Savitri
> 76. Atma
> 77. Pasupata
> 78. Parabrahma
> 79. Avadhutaka
> 80. Tripuratapini
> 81. Devi
> 82. Tripura
> 83. Katharudra
> 84. Bhavana
> 85. Rudrahridaya
> 86. Yoga-kundali
> 87. Bhasma
> 88. Rudraksha
> 89. Ganapati
> 90. Darsana
> 91. Tarasara
> 92. Mahavakya
> 93. Panchabrahma
> 94. Pranagnihotra
> 95. Gopalatapini
> 96. Krishna
> 97. Yajnavalkya
> 98. Varaha
> 99. Satyayani
> 100. Hayagriva
> 101. Dattatreya
> 102. Garuda
> 103. Kalisamtarana
> 104. Jabali
> 105. Saubhagyalakshmi
> 106. Sarasvatirahasya
> 107. Bahvricha
> 108. Muktika

The Muktika Upanishad also classifies them according to what Veda they come from and it lists what it considers the most important Upanishads.

You can read all 108 Upanishads in English in [this website](http://www.celextel.org/upanishads/).  And you can read them in a single PDF file [here](http://cincinnatitemple.com/downloads/Upanishad-Complete.pdf).

One note of caution: as I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3012/36), the Muktika Upanishads was passed down with very little rigor, in contrast to the extremely rigorous process used to pass down the Samhitas of the Vedas.  So just because an Upanishad is listed in the Muktika Upanishad doesn't necessarily mean that it's authentic.  On the other hand, if an Upanishad is not on the list, then it's almost guaranteed to be less than a few hundred years old.  (Or at least that's when it started being considered an Upanishad as opposed to some other kind of work.)

Comment: Also, one way of ascertaining the validity of a Upanishad is to see which Upanishads have been upheld by Sampradayas. Though, Shankara commented on 10 Upanishads, he has mentioned elsewhere few other Upanishads as well.Advaita Acharyas have spoken about Upanishads over the centuries. Upanishad Brahmendra has commented upon all the 108 Upanishads of Muktika. Hence, irrespective of current historical/literary analysis, the traditional view is that all 108 Upanishads are valid. Otherwise, Brahmendra would not have commented upon them all. So, we need to take view of Sampradaya Acharyas as well.

Comment: @NithinSridhar I can certainly understand those who are in the disicipic succession of Upanishad Brahmendra accepting all 108 Upanishads.  But I don't belong to the Advaita Sampradayam, so I don't accept Upanishad Brahmendra as an authority.  But yeah, I agree broadly with the principle that we should see what Upanishads our Acharyas have commented on and referenced in determining authenticity.

Comment: Yes. I agree with you. In fact you may consult with Acharyas in your own Sampradaya and follow as they propose.

Comment: @NithinSridhar Yeah, that's more or less what I do - I'm a Sri Vaishnava, so I accept all the Upanishads referenced by Ramanujacharya and other Sri Vaishnava Acharyas.  Plus I accept all the Upanishads referenced by Adi Shankaracharya, because he was living so early, and all the Upanishads that are associated with a Vedic Shakha that is still available.  That comes to about 30 Upanishads. Beyond that, I treat the remaining Upanishads in the list of 108 with skepticism, and I determine whether to accept them or not based on their content, the style of language, etc.

Comment: Last portion of your comment is significant. We can always cross check the content of minor Upanishads with similar contents in other Upanishads to verify. Ultimately, personal Sadhana is what matters. 

For example, though Ganapati Atharvashirsha ia very famous, yet many consider it unauthentic. But, as a Sadhana it is very potent. Even in terms of philosophy I have found it in sync with major Upanishads. So, as far as I am considered, it is Authentic for me.

Comment: @NithinSridhar Well, I think the Ganapati Atharvashirsha Upanishad is not an authentic Upanishad, but I think it's mantras and the like came from Agamas originally.  So I'm not doubting its practical usefulness, I'm just saying that it was not originally part of the Vedas.  If it was originally part of the Vedas there would be some record of it before the 1700's.  And it wasn't even commented on by Upanishad Brahmendra.  I'm fine calling it a Hindu scripture or at least a copy of content from actual Hindu scriptures, I just object to the terms "Atharvashirsha" and "Upanishad".

Comment: Yes. I agree here. Even I dont consider it as Upanishad as such. Only that it is Authentic Hindu scripture.

Comment: You may find this link interesting- http://www.advaita-vedanta.in/authentic-upanishads-and-gitas

Comment: @NithinSridhar Thanks!  That's a great link.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Thanks for the sources. Can you also a provide a source where original sanskrit verses are given along with translation and if possible transliteration?

Comment: @Naveen You're welcome.  You can read the Upanishads in both Devanagari and ITRANS (English transliteration) here: http://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskrit/by-category/doc_upanishhat.php I don't know of any source that gives all 108 Upanishads in Sanskrit interspersed with translations, but I think the website I linked to in my answer gives verse by verse translations of all the Upanishads, just without the Sanskrit verses.  But I do have the principal 10 Upanishads interspersed with Sanskrit, English, and Adi Shankaracharya's commentary if you're interested in that.

Comment: @NithinSridhar Concerning the issue of what Upanishads are authentic, you may be interested in my question here, about an Upanishad which is not in the list of 108, but whose authenticity we can be sure of because it's found in a known Vedic Shakha: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10190/36

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Its indeed interesting. I guess we may safely take it as authentic after analyzing the contents once I guess! I guess our acharyas would be able to easily get it translated you know.