# What is the meaning of this mantra from Chakshupanishad?

Tags: mantras, upanishads

Does anyone know what is the meaning of following mantra?

> प्राण विखंडन मन्त्र -
> ।। ॐ तच्चक्षुर्देवहितं पुरस्ताच्छुक्रमुच्चरत्‌ हूं फट् ।।
>
> prāṇa vikhaṃḍana mantra -
> ।। oṃ taccakṣurdevahitaṃ purastācchukramuccarat‌ hūṃ phaṭ ।।

This is a cryptic mantra taken from the said upanishad by taking first letter of mantras like acronym. I want to find meanings of all that mantra and find all the slocks in full. If possible please share the upanishad if anybody have it.

Comment: Not familiar with this. Here is a list of the Upanishads - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8947/available-sources-for-the-108-upanishads

Answer (score 1):

> प्राण विखंडन मन्त्र - ।। ॐ तच्चक्षुर्देवहितं पुरस्ताच्छुक्रमुच्चरत्‌
>   हूं फट् ।।

It seems that the above mantra you quoted in the post is not present in the Chakshupanishad. This Upanishad is related to the tradition of Krishna Yajurveda and this is one of the minor Upanishad among 108 Upanishads.

The purpose of this Upanishad is to cure eye related defects and to enhance eye power, by means of worship of the Sun God with mantras. The Rishi of the Upanishad is Ahirbudhnya  - Meter is Gayatri and Devata is Surya.

---

As required by you  - here is the link of [**Chakshupanishad**](https://archive.org/details/HindiBook-108UpanishadsPart-3SadhanaKhand/page/n55) by Pandit Sri Ram Sharma Acharya of AWGP in Hindi.

Comment: I find the part of this mantra can be from [Taittiriya Aranyaka](https://sa.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D(%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B0)/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A0%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AA).

Comment: @Pandya -Oh nice find. BTW hello, will talk later on in chat. :- )

Comment: Yes, sure! will talk on chat room :)