# Ganapati Gayatri Mantra | In which Shastra it is contained this mantra and who wrote it firstly?

Tags: mantras, dharma-shastras, ganesha, gayatri-mantra, itihasa

This very mantra for Shree Ganesha

Who wrote it for first?

Which Shastra- Veda or others- contain that?

Dhanyawaad
Thank you

https://www.thedivineindia.com/ganpati-gayatri-mantra/5889

Comment: Found in Atharvasheerha which is part of Ganapati upanishad. See for more info: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2953/21353

Comment: Thank you @Proxy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mantra you are referring to (the one that is found the link given in the question) is Ganapaty Gayatri mantra viz:

> Aum Ekadantaya Viddhamahe, Vakratundaya Dhimahi, Tanno Danti
> Prachodayat॥

It is originally from the [Mahanarayana Upanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/mahanarayana.html). The Upanishad has a separate section containing Gayatri mantras of various deities.

> गायत्र्याः ।
>
> तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे महादेवाय धीमहि । तन्नो रुद्रः प्रचोदयात् ॥ २३॥
> (tatpurushaya vidmahe mahadevaya dhimahi | tanno rudrah prachodayat
> ||)
>
> **तत्पुरुषाय विद्महे वक्रतुण्डाय धीमहि । तन्नो दन्तिः प्रचोदयात् ॥ २४॥
> (tatpurushaya vidmahe vakratundaya dhimahi | tanno dantih prachodayat**
> ||)

The Upanishad is associated with Krishna Yajurveda. And, Upanishads don't have authors.

Comment: Dhanyabada mere mitra @Rickross Thank you my friend it means.

Comment: anek dhanybad @hindustudent-TheWhiteHindu

Comment: Balobashi tumaro pryie

Comment: Which is the exact and precise vedic version? "Ekadantaya vidmahe" or "Tatpurushaya vidmahe"?. Please answer this.

Comment: @ShaivamruthaSudhakara.tatpurushaya ... sorry I was late in replying .. I came online only now

Answer (score 3):

*Ganapati Gayatri Mantra* is found in **Ganapati Atharvashirsha Upanishad**.

[image: Revelation of the mahamantra]

[image: Origin and seer]

*Credits: Commentary on Ganapati Atharvashirsha Upanishad by Swami Tejomayananda*

**Edit**: The mantra referred to in the link is correctly addressed by *Rickross.*